# How to control the potential in multiple-electrodes (3 or more) in electrochemical cells?

Tags: batteries, biopotential, electrode, electrochemical

Usually, in most cell designs, the concept of two-electrode design is the baseline. The two electrodes are anode and cathode where the electron transfer happens between them. However, I have been reading about 3 electrodes and 4 electrodes designs where the new electrodes are used to control the potential while allowing the working electrodes to deal with the current transfer. However, I wanted to know how to control the potential of my cell and what is the equations for that if I want to build my own multi-electrode cell.

Thank you

Comment: First, what is the cell doing? Electrolysis, plating, hydrogen generation, measurement of chemical reactions, or is it a battery?

Comment: it is a battery

Comment: You measure the Impedance mismatch and voltage mismatch and then balance the differences to <<1% amd stay well within the chemistry voltage operating range.